# Understanding DynamoDB keys

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, primary-key

I have read the DynamoDB documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/Welcome.html). My scenario is little different to nominate any field as key to retrieve. My data looks like

```
RandomID(Unique)  Category  date_created   isUsed
------------------------------------------------------
12355              ABC      03/02            false
14682              ABC      03/02            false
19684              ABC      03/20            false
12357              BCA      03/04            true
16924              ABC      03/14            true
12352              ABC      03/02            true
32358              BCA      03/14            false
```

**RandomId:** only unique thing in the table and which needs to be retrieved.

**Category:** each category can have any number of assigned and unassigned randomids.

**creationDate:** when Randomids are created

**isUsed:** whether the randomids is already used or not.

I wanted to get 2 unused (isUsed='false') random ids(ifexists) for a single category?
Example: If I query my table 'Give me two unUsed ids for category 'ABC'' then I should get any one of these results

```
{12355, 14682}
{14682, 19684}
{12355, 19684}
```

My question are:
1. What is my hashkey here? because only unique thing in this table is my randomid.

2. Thought of keeping 'isUsed' as sort key but boolean is not accepted as sort key? I couldn't find the category while creating a sample table in Dyanmo.
3. What are my keys?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can precompute the result. Instead of using a boolean isUsed, why don't you use an optional attribute (string) called `locationUsed` and update the item when you first use one of your random ids. If you create a GSI with partition key `randomID` and sort key `locationUsed` then this GSI will only contain items with random IDs that your application already used. You can guard yourself from race conditions between this GSI view and your base table by using conditional updates on random id items, specifically have a `ConditionExpression = attribute_not_exists(locationUsed)`.